# Hosting a NextJS project on Amplify with dynamic routes

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering

I have a NextJS project hosted on AWS Amplify and I'm having trouble serving this content to the users. I already identified the problem, but can't find any clear path to solve this as everything I've tried has failed.

### Problem Explanation

The logic is straightforward. There is a database where students can be saved and when the dynamic routes for student pages are created (through `getStaticProps()` and `getStaticPaths()`) a request is done to the database to get all possible student IDs. The problem arises when the site is already built and you add a new student to the database; when this is done Amplify doesn't rebuild the static pages and thus the path to the new student (which actually exists in the DB) is not found because the original build didn't consider this new ID.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
   const studentIds = await getAllStudentIds();

   const paths = studentIds.map((studentId) => {
       // Each object must have the params key and contain an object with the id key (because we’re using [id] in the file name).
       return {
           params: {
               id: studentId,
           },
       };
   });

   return {
       paths,
       fallback: false,
   };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
   const studentDataObject = await getStudentInformation(params.id);

   // Convert to serializable data type for return.
   const studentData = JSON.stringify(studentDataObject);

   return {
       props: {
           studentData,
       },
   };
}
```

I've gone through the NextJS docs and it is clear to me that the easiest solution to this problem is to set [`fallback: true`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-true) on the `getStaticPaths` function, but when I deploy this to Amplify Hosting the build fails because the [Amplify's supported features](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/ssr-Amplify-support.html#supported-unsupported-features). After this I tried to solve using the [`fallback: "blocking`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-blocking) functionality, but this doesn't seem to work in the Amplify Hosting environment, when I try to access this page I get a 500 error (in my local machine this works just fine).

### What I'm looking for

I solved the aforementioned problem by simply creating a query string route and serving this information directly on the client. However, I'm sure I'll need to add dynamic routes in the future (it is important that these routes update beyond the build) and would like to know of any possible solutions.

> I've already tried some of the things mentioned in [this discussion](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/2268) of the Amplify GitHub repository, but this doesn't work on my side (when I set `fallback: "blocking"` I get a 500 error on Amplify Hosting environment).

I know the solution to this is probably very basic, so thanks for taking the time!